# How to set UIImageView Size and how to make sure it stays that size all the time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, augmented-reality

I've been experimenting on augmented reality with iOS using this library: https://github.com/promet/PRAugmentedReality

I added another xib named "POIDetails" for displaying details of my points of interest. I added a button for returning back to camera screen by this code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:self completion:nil];
```

But when i return back the AR screen, the POI image gets enormous.

I tried to set height contraint to 50 and aspect to 1:1 But it didn't do any good. I tried to use sizeThatFits like this:

```
[myPOI sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
```

But it didn't work too. After seeing no difference, I set back everything i did on image's sizing.

Below you can see before and after images and google drive link for downloading my project. How can i make sure this image doesn't get out of 50 px height?

Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-cDfWHidgvcVVFRNll0OVR2UTA/view?usp=sharing

Here's my ARObject.m file

```
#import "ARObject.h"
#import "POIDetails.h"


@interface ARObject ()

@end


@implementation ARObject

@synthesize arTitle, distance;

- (id)initWithId:(int)newId
           title:(NSString*)newTitle
     coordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinates
andCurrentLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)currLoc
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        arId = newId;

        arTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:newTitle];

        lat = newCoordinates.latitude;
        lon = newCoordinates.longitude;

        distance = @([self calculateDistanceFrom:currLoc]);

        [self.view setTag:newId];
    }
    return self;
}

-(double)calculateDistanceFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)user_loc_coord
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D object_loc_coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);

    CLLocation *object_location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:object_loc_coord.latitude
                                                              longitude:object_loc_coord.longitude];
    CLLocation *user_location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:user_loc_coord.latitude
                                                            longitude:user_loc_coord.longitude];

    return [object_location distanceFromLocation:user_location];
}
-(NSString*)getDistanceLabelText
{
    if (distance.doubleValue > POINT_ONE_MILE_METERS)
         return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f mi", distance.doubleValue*METERS_TO_MILES];
    else return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f ft", distance.doubleValue*METERS_TO_FEET];
}

- (NSDictionary*)getARObjectData
{
    NSArray *keys = @[@"id",@"title", @"latitude", @"longitude", @"distance"];

    NSArray *values = @[@(arId),
                       arTitle,
                       @(lat),
                       @(lon),
                       distance];
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [titleL setText:arTitle];

    [distanceL setText:[self getDistanceLabelText]];
}

-(void)myPOITapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"image click");
    POIDetails *poiDetails = [[POIDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"POIDetails" bundle:nil]; // constructor
    [self presentViewController:poiDetails animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// viewDidLoad wasn't in the library, timur added this method
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    myPOI.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    myPOI.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES;

    [myPOI setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *myPOITap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myPOITapping:)];
    [myPOITap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [myPOI addGestureRecognizer:myPOITap];
    [self.view addSubview:myPOI];
}

#pragma mark -- OO Methods

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ARObject %d - %@ - lat: %f - lon: %f - distance: %@",
            arId, arTitle, lat, lon, distance];
}

@end
```

---

**Edit:**

I added following codes to my ARObject.m file's viewDidLoad function and It seems to keep image in set resolution.

myPOI.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
myPOI.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES;

But I'm still having issues with my distance label. I set top and bottom spacing constraint to nearest neighbour and label is now half way up but still seperated from my point of interest image like this:

[image]

---

---

---

Before:
 [image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to set height contraint to 50 and aspect to 1:1 But it didn't do any good

Check if `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of your `UIImageView` instance is set to `NO` when you using constraints.

Also check if `UIImageView`'s instance `contentMode` property set to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`

---

### ARObject.m

```
CGRect myRect;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    /*
     keep existed in this method code
    */

    /*
     move [self.view addSubview:myPOI] line to here, leave all other in viewDidLoad 
    */

    if (myRect.size.height != 0) {self.view.frame = myRect;}
    [self.view addSubview:myPOI];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    myRect = self.view.frame;
    [myPOI removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myRect = CGRectZero;

    /*
     all your other code
    */    
}
```

Unfortunately I cant test code, because device required for this project.

Comment: I added following code to myARObject.m file's viewDidLoad. It seems to fix image resizing issue but still distance label is way above to the point. Adding screenshot to my question in a min.

myPOI.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
myPOI.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES;

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. You need to set myPOI.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO if you are using constraints

Comment: I added ARObject.m file. Also image doesn't display correctly when i set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO. It works properly when i set it to YES

Comment: You can download the project from google drive link above

Comment: Thanks. There is problems with positioning ARObject in superview. Fast simple solution without code analyze is to move your code from viewDidLoad method to viewWillAppear, and add method viewWillDissapear in which you should "roll back", remove myPOI from superview.

Comment: Also maybe will help to capture ARObject view.frame property in viewWillDissapear and restore it in viewWillAppear

Comment: ok. how do i do that? I'm little bit confused about viewWillDissapear

Comment: it looks like the distance label got together but it doesn't display distance. Also now, point of interests doesn't show up their original locations, they change after i go back